# How to build this query?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

i have table
http://oi58.tinypic.com/2s7xreo.jpg

```
 id    action_date  type  item_id  quantity
---    -----------  ----  -------  --------
 87    4/25/2014    1     s-1           100
 88    4/1/2014     1     s-1           150
 89    4/4/2014     1     s-1           200
 90    4/3/2014     1     s-2           222
 91    4/7/2014     1     s-2            10
 96    4/4/2014     1     s-2             8
 97    4/22/2014    1     s-2             8
 98    4/21/2014    2     s-1           255
 99    4/5/2014     2     s-1             6
100    4/6/2014     2     s-2           190
101    4/6/2014     2     s-3            96
102    4/8/2014     2     s-1           120
103    4/15/2014    2     s-2             3
104    4/16/2014    2     s-2             3
```

type column which mean if 1 this is in item to my shop >>> if 2 this is out item from my shop >>

i need query to give me result like this

```
item   in   out   net 

s1     300  195  105
```

and so on >>

how to write query that give me this result >>
and if i must but them in tow table >> table for the in and table for the out if that help >>> how it build the query >
and thanx in advance :)

note :: i am work on access

Comment: this is image for the table 
http://oi58.tinypic.com/2s7xreo.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get the result is to use an aggregate function on an expression that conditionally returns the value of `quantity`, based on the value of `type`.

```
SELECT t.item
     , SUM(CASE WHEN t.type = 1 THEN t.quantity ELSE 0 END) AS in_
     , SUM(CASE WHEN t.type = 2 THEN t.quantity ELSE 0 END) AS out_
     , SUM(CASE WHEN t.type = 1 THEN t.quantity ELSE 0 END) 
       - SUM(CASE WHEN t.type = 2 THEN t.quantity ELSE 0 END) AS net_
  FROM mytable t
 GROUP BY t.item
```

This approach works in Oracle, as well as MySQL and SQL Server.

(If you remove the `SUM()` aggregate function and the `GROUP BY` clause, you can see how that `CASE` expression is working. The query above gives the result you specified, this one is just a demonstration that helps "explain" how that query works.)

```
SELECT t.item
     , CASE WHEN t.type = 1 THEN t.quantity ELSE 0 END AS in_
     , CASE WHEN t.type = 2 THEN t.quantity ELSE 0 END AS out_
     , t.*
  FROM mytable t
```

---

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately, Microsoft Access doesn't support `CASE` expressions. But Access does have an `iif` function. The same approach should work, the syntax might be something like this:

```
SELECT t.item
     , SUM(iif(t.type = 1, t.quantity, 0) AS in_
     , SUM(iif(t.type = 2, t.quantity, 0) AS out_
     , SUM(iif(t.type = 1, t.quantity, 0)
       - SUM(iif(t.type = 2, t.quantity, 0) AS net_
  FROM mytable t
 GROUP BY t.item
```

Comment: case is not supported in access 
is there any one know the alternative for this in ms access ? 
 but it correct answer but i dont know how to implement it on ms access

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT item_id,
       In_col,
       Out_col,
       (In_col - Out_col) AS Net
FROM
  (SELECT item_id,
          sum(CASE WHEN TYPE = 1 THEN quantity END) AS In_col,
          sum(CASE WHEN TYPE = 2 THEN quantity END) AS Out_col
   FROM TABLE
   GROUP BY item_id) AS t1;
```

I hope this what you need.